# Discrete path tracking with python gekko

Tags: gekko

I have some discrete data points representing a path and I want to minimize the distance between a trajectory of an object to these path points along with some other constraints. I'm trying out gekko as a tool to solve this problem and for that I made a simple problem by making data points from a parabola and a constraint to the path. My attempt to solve it is

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#path data points
x_ref = np.linspace(0, 4, num=21)
y_ref = - np.square(x_ref) + 16

#constraint for visualization purposes
x_bound = np.linspace(0, 4, num=10)
y_bound = 1.5*x_bound + 4

def distfunc(x,y,xref,yref,p):
    '''
    Shortest distance from (x,y) to (xref, yref)
    '''

    dtemp = []
    for i in range(len(xref)):
        d = (x-xref[i])**2+(y-yref[i])**2
        dtemp.append(dtemp)
    min_id = dtemp.index(min(dtemp))
    if min_id == 0:
        next_id = min_id+1
    elif min_id == len(x_ref):
        next_id = min_id-1
    else:
        d2 = (x-xref[min_id-1])**2+(y-yref[min_id-1])**2
        d1 = (x-xref[min_id+1])**2+(y-yref[mid_id+1])**2
        d_next = [d2, d1]
        next_id = min_id + 2*d_next.index(min(d_next)) - 1
    n1 = xref[next_id] - xref[min_id]
    n2 = yref[next_id] - yref[min_id]
    nnorm = p.sqrt(n1**2+n2**2)
    n1 = n1 / nnorm
    n2 = n2 / nnorm
    difx = x-xref[min_id]
    dify = y-yref[min_id]
    dot = difx*n1 + dify*n2
    deltax = difx - dot*n1
    deltay = dify - dot*n2
    return deltax**2+deltay**2

v_ref = 3
now = time.time()

p = GEKKO(remote=False)
p.time = np.linspace(0,10,21)
x = p.Var(value=0)
y = p.Var(value=16)
vx = p.Var(value=1)
vy = p.Var(value=0)
ax = p.Var(value=0)
ay = p.Var(value=0)
p.options.IMODE = 6
p.options.SOLVER = 3
p.options.WEB = 0

x_refg = p.Param(value=x_ref)
y_refg = p.Param(value=y_ref)

x_refg = p.Param(value=x_ref)
y_refg = p.Param(value=y_ref)
v_ref = p.Const(value=v_ref)


p.Obj(distfunc(x,y,x_refg,y_refg,p))
p.Obj( (p.sqrt(vx**2+vy**2) - v_ref)**2 + ax**2 + ay**2)

p.Equation(x.dt()==vx)
p.Equation(y.dt()==vy)
p.Equation(vx.dt()==ax)
p.Equation(vy.dt()==ay)
p.Equation(y>=1.5*x+4)
p.solve(disp=False, debug=True)
print(f'run time: {time.time()-now}')

plt.plot(x_ref, y_ref)
plt.plot(x_bound, y_bound)
plt.plot(x1.value,x2.value)
plt.show()
```

[This is the result that I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u1fu.png) As you can see, its not exactly the solution that one should expect. For reference to a solution that you may expect, [here is what I get using the cost function below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZrMV.png)

```
p.Obj((x-x_refg)**2 + (y-y_refg)**2 + ax**2 + ay**2)
```

However since what I actually wanted is the shortest distance to a path described by these points I expect the *distfunc* to be closer to what I want since the shortest distance is most likely to some interpolated point. So my question is twofold:

1. Is this the correct gekko expression/formulation for the objective function?
2. My other goal is solution speed so is there a more efficient way of expressing this problem for gekko?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define an objective function that changes based on conditions unless you insert logical conditions that are continuously differentiable such as with the `if2` or `if3` function. Gekko evaluates the symbolic model once and then passes that off to an executable for solution. It only calls the Python model build once because it is compiling the model to efficient byte-code for execution. You can see the model that you created with `p.open_folder()`. The model file ends in the `apm` extension: `gk_model0.apm`.

```py
Model
Constants
    i0 = 3
End Constants
Parameters
    p1
    p2
    p3
    p4
End Parameters
Variables
    v1 = 0
    v2 = 16
    v3 = 1
    v4 = 0
    v5 = 0
    v6 = 0
End Variables
Equations
    v3=$v1
    v4=$v2
    v5=$v3
    v6=$v4
    v2>=(((1.5)*(v1))+4)
    minimize (((((v1-0.0)-((((((v1-0.0))*((0.2/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))+(((v2-16.0))&
             *((-0.03999999999999915/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))))*&
             ((0.2/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))))^(2))+((((v2-16.0)&
             -((((((v1-0.0))*((0.2/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))+(((v2-16.0))&
             *((-0.03999999999999915/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))))&
             *((-0.03999999999999915/sqrt(0.04159999999999994))))))^(2)))
    minimize (((((sqrt((((v3)^(2))+((v4)^(2))))-i0))^(2))+((v5)^(2)))+((v6)^(2)))
End Equations

End Model
```

One strategy is to split your problem into multiple optimization problems that are all [minimal time problems](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime) where you navigate to the first way-point and then re-initialize the problem to navigate to the second way-point, and so on. If you want to preserve momentum and anticipate the turning then you'll need to use more advanced methods such as shown in the [Pigeon / Eagle tracking problem](https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/Report_hawk2016.pdf) (see [source files](https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/Report_hawk2016.zip)) or similar to a [trajectory optimization with UAVs](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/index.php/Projects/PathPlanning) or HALE UAVs (see references below).

- Martin, R.A., Gates, N., Ning, A., Hedengren, J.D., [Dynamic Optimization of High-Altitude Solar Aircraft Trajectories Under Station-Keeping Constraints](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/uploads/Members/2018_hale_martin.pdf), Journal of Guidance, Control, and Dynamics, 2018, doi: 10.2514/1.G003737.
- Gates, N.S., Moore, K.R., Ning, A., Hedengren, J.D., [Combined Trajectory, Propulsion and Battery Mass Optimization for Solar-Regenerative High-Altitude Long Endurance Unmanned Aircraft](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/2982/), AIAA Science and Technology Forum (SciTech), 2019.

Comment: Thank you for all the references. I'll take a deeper look into each of them.